# Short term visit visa for UAE: after which date should I leave?

Tags: visas, dubai

I am traveling to Dubai on 18th December, I have taken a 30 days short term visa.

I have booked the return ticket on 16th Jan 2016, 22:55 hrs. Will there be any problem as my stay is exactly 30 days and I am returning on the 30th day night.

Kindly some one advice. it would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You visa is valid till the end of that day (midnight). As your flight is at 10:55 PM, you'll need to clear immigration at least by 9:00 PM - which gives you plenty of time.

If, for any reason, there is a delay of any sort - and you don't pass immigration by midnight - you would then be subject to an overstay ban and possible deportation.

Comment: It's not perhaps worth to notice that the 'delay of any sort' don't have to be caused by the passenger to make problems. If a flight reschedule, strike, bad weather or any other reason not warranted by the passenger causes him to not to be able to pass immigration before the visa expires, the passenger will usually be held liable for the visa overstay.